# PHP Getting a value out of an array

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I have the following array extracted from a CSV file.

```
 $line =    Array ( 
            [0] => First 
            [1] => Last 
            [2] => 102338100053 
            [3] => https://url.com/SKnuDbowTveUsHXwMAnixg?t=kIMVJtQ 
            [4] => 48a9ee0d-ba30-4ef7-94b0-75f03009e2c6 
            [5] => 1436.75 
            [6] => 21.55125 
        )
```

I am trying to get the value of [2]

I extract it like this

```
$number2 = $line[2];
```

This is fine. I get the following response. 102338100053

When I try to extract the first 6 numbers from the variable using

```
$Identifier = substr($number2 ,0,6)
```

I only get 2 numbers: 10

if I use 12

```
$siteIdentifier = substr($number2 ,0,12)
```

I get: 102338

I found this confusing so I checked the variable with urlencode

```
echo urlencode($number2);
```

This is what I received: %001%000%002%003%003%008%001%000%000%000%005%003%00

I need to get just the number and I dont know what to do to get it, as I am searching for this in a database and its not finding it?

Can someone please assist?

Comment: Try to debug `var_dump($updateMembernumber,$number2)`

Comment: Try $Identifier = $updatedMembernumber % 1000000;

Comment: `$updateMembernumber !== $number2`. check that you used  2 different variables. As it's working for me:- https://eval.in/997902

Comment: Sorry, updatedmembernumber was supposed to be number2

Comment: working example :  https://eval.in/997905

Comment: @Arvind I did the var_dump on $number2 and it came back with string(25) "102338100053"

Comment: @AlivetoDie I have tried the same with just creating the array, but getting this one from a CSV file, it gives me something different. var_dump on $number2 came back with string(25) "102338100053"

Answer (score 0):

You may try using [gettype()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php) which gives you the datatype of your variables. Then the rest must be pretty simple to understand. I used `$i<6` condition because you've mentioned you want only the first six integers.

```
$i= 0;
foreach($line as $key => $value){
if(gettype($value) == integer){
if($i<6){
          $ints[$i] = $value;
          $i++;
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Simply `Try this` kind of answer is not very helpful.